# Append data to every row of a query result set

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, append, array-push

I have a simple query that looks for the same id inside the `$_SESSION['cart_items']` keys. This is the output:

[image]

and the code:

```
$statement = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (".implode(',',array_keys($_SESSION['cart_items'])).")");

$data = array();

while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);
```

This works fine but I want to add a 5th element inside the array. The value will be coming from the value of the associative array `$_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']]` inside the while loop. So far what I did:

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
    if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $_SESSION['cart_items']))
    {
        $another = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']];
        array_push($data, $another);
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

But I get this output:

[image]

As you can see, there is an additional `[1]=>23` and `[3]=>47` but that's not what I want to happen. What I want to happen is something like this:

[image]

I want it to be a part of the array inside an array. Or more like the 5th element. Can I do something like this?

Comment: Using `$statement` as the variable name for a "result set" is misleading.  I recommend `$result` or `$resultSet`.  `$statement` or `$stmt` is appropriate when you have declared a prepared statement (you aren't declaring a prepared statement though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and tell me if it working for you !

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {

    if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $_SESSION['cart_items']))
    {
        $another = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']];
        array_push($row, $another);
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}

print_r($data);
```

For your second question try this and let me know

```
 while($row = $statement->fetch()) {

if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $_SESSION['cart_items']))
{
    $another = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']];

    $new_row = $row+array("YOUR_TEXT" => $another);

}
  $data[] = $new_row;
}
 print_r($data);
```

Comment: what do you mean by new key ?

Comment: no no its ok ! i did not get your question that's why i asked you ! ask clearly to get answer ! thank u !

Comment: I mean instead of [4]=>47, I also want [randomtext] => 47 :D

Answer (score 1):

the reason it does not inserted to your sub array
because you push it into your main array which is
the $data

SOLUTION: 
before pushing it 
create a new variable

```
$newRow = $row;
```

then: 
push your 5th element

```
$another = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']];
array_push($newRow, $another);
```

then lastly you push your new row which contains your 5th element to $data

```
$data[] = $newRow;
```

so your new php code would be like this

```
<?php


while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $newRow = $row;
    if(array_key_exists($row['id'], $_SESSION['cart_items']))
    {
        $another = $_SESSION['cart_items'][$row['id']];
        array_push($newRow, $another);
    }
    $data[] = $newRow;
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to relate and map data between your session array and your database table, then I don't see any reason to avoid SQL for this task.

This dynamic SQL will serve your `WHERE` requirements and allow your table schema to change over time without causing key collisions in the PHP code.  Furthermore, because there is no PHP processing, you can enjoy a `fetch_all()` instead of using a loop to transfer the result set data to a 2d array.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/Rp))

```
$_SESSION = [
    'cart_items' => [
        35 => 47,
        1 => 23,
    ]
];
$derivedSubqueries = [];
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $k => $v) {
    $derivedSubqueries[] = sprintf(
        "SELECT %d prod_id, %d another",
        $k,
        $v
    );
}

$sql = 'SELECT product.*,
               derived.another
        FROM product
        JOIN (
            ' . implode("\n\t    UNION\n\t    ", $derivedSubqueries) . '
        ) derived ON product.id = derived.prod_id';
echo "\t$sql\n\n";

foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row) . "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
    SELECT product.*,
           derived.another
    FROM product
    JOIN (
        SELECT 35 prod_id, 47 another
        UNION
        SELECT 1 prod_id, 23 another
    ) derived ON product.id = derived.prod_id

{"id":"1","name":"ballpen","price":"15","quantity":"50","another":"23"}
{"id":"35","name":"qwe","price":"2","quantity":"19","another":"47"}
```